# Two animation to fadeIn at the same time?

Tags: jquery, html, css, animation, css-animations

I'm trying to get two animations to fadeIn onto the screen at the same time. This is impossible currently because one animation is waiting until the 'typed.js effect' to finish before counting the animation-delay.

So in order to have two animationsfadeIn at the same time I have to set different animation-delay.

The jsfiddle shows the problem:

https://jsfiddle.net/harrydry/p4ev1nj2/13/

Merely setting the animation delay to two different types so that they come on in sync is not a solution. As the whole animation is far more complex and this won't work. 
I have used the css animations plugin as shown here:

```
<span class="line1 animated fadeIn">Jim Jarmusch</span>
```

Answer (score -1):

if `jQuery` `fadeIn()` is an option, you can use a common class as selector and the animation will be simultaneous:

**HTML**

```
<div style="display:none" class="test">
  Test 1
</div>
<div style="display:none" class="test">
  Test 2
</div>
<div style="display:none" class="test">
  Test 3
</div>
<div style="display:none" class="test">
  Test 4
</div>
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.test').fadeIn('slow');
});
```

**Fiddle**

https://jsfiddle.net/ygzyoyxx/